# php code to delete 2 folder from the present folder script

Tags: php, html

```
rmdir(getcwd()."../../users/".$foldername, 0777);
```

The script is present in :

> C:/wamp/www/share/admin/pages/drop.php

I want to delete the `$foldername` present in `/admin/users/$foldername`

Comment: i believe my problem is from the directory linking

Comment: Just at a quick glance, you have too many `../` You are in `admin/pages/` and want to go back to `admin/` before traversing to `admin/users`

Comment: You should echo out the result to confirm what folder it thinks it is working from.  `echo getcwd() . "../users/" . $foldername";`

Comment: so how do i move out of the pages folder back to the admin folder and to users folder.

Comment: If you want to remove a directory (which your php script has permissions on) use unlink Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php